# Começou o Winter Bash 2015

Tags: debate, winterbash-2015

Mais um fim de ano se aproxima, e com isso o evento que espalha alegria e felicidade por todo o mundo (e um pouquinho de desgosto em quem mora abaixo do Equador<sup>1</sup>): **Winter Bash!**

[image: Ou... Summer Bash pra muitos de vocês]

De hoje até o dia 3 de Janeiro de 2016, você vai poder ganhar vários chapéus diferentes e exibi-los para o mundo todo. Basta continuar usando o site, fazendo as mesmas coisas que já vinha fazendo antes. Assim como nos anos anteriores, temos uma coleção totalmente nova de chapéus. (Isso é porque nós amamos todos vocês e acreditamos que vocês sempre merecem o melhor, e não porque esquecemos de salvar a lista do ano passado… Obviamente).

Então palmas para o nosso designer freelance [Elias Stein](http://www.eliasstein.com), que usou seu talento para converter todas as nossas ideias em belos chapéus digitais, pelo terceiro ano consecutivo, e também para o *Senhor dos Unicórnios* - o primeiro e único [balpha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/24/balpha)! Mais uma vez ele trabalhou incansavelmente para garantir que ninguém ficaria sem seus chapéus.

Pra quem não sabe como funciona, os chapéus são como medalhas, só que **melhores**, já que você pode usar os chapéus no seu avatar, e exibi-los em todos os lugares da rede onde sua foto aparece! (E graças ao [Brian Nickel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23142/brian-nickel), esse ano o aplicativo iOS também faz parte da festa!) Os requisitos para ganhar um chapéu são um pouco diferentes dos requisitos para medalhas. Se quiser saber como conseguir os seus, dê uma olhada no [mini-site do Winter Bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com). No total são 28 chapéus…oficialmente. Será que existem chapéus secretos? Quantos são? Como ganhá-los?
Sei lá… vocês vão ter que descobrir sozinhos!

Quando você quiser usar seus chapéus, basta acessar o seu perfil, em qualquer site da rede, e escolher um chapéu para vestir (ou admirá-los na sua estante). É só clicar no gorro em cima da das suas medalhas.

[image: Gorro no verão é uma opção arriscada]

(O gorro é para deixar suas medalhas aquecidas então não, você não pode usá-lo)

[image: Nem tudo que é um chapéu tem que ser um chapéu mesmo, certo?]

Depois de escolher um chapéu para usar, você pode escolher o tamanho e posição que melhor se encaixe no seu avatar. O exemplo do ano passado é perfeito demais para não ser usado de novo:

[image: Shog9: Caçador de Vampiros]

Você vai ver uma nova notificação, especial para o Winter Bash, sempre que ganhar um chapéu novo, então é fácil saber quando você pode dar uma atualizada na aparência: [image: É bastante reputação, hein...].

E se você acha que esse negócio todo não serve pra nada, sem problema! Clique no floco de neve na barra superior para escolher não participar do evento —[image: neve? Em pleno verão???]— e depois no link que diz “Eu odeio chapéus” no rodapé da janela. (No Stack Overflow em Inglês, funciona ao contrário. Você precisa fazer a mesma coisa mas para **participar** do evento). Sempre lembrando que você pode mudar de ideia a qualquer momento e mudar sua opção.

Não se esqueça também que os chapéus vão desaparecer em três semanas, então não perca tempo! Tem gente que já tá correndo atrás do diploma<sup>2</sup>!

[image: Tradução por: Eu mesmo]

---

1: *Como em anos anteriores, a tradição venceu ao nomear o evento. Esperamos que todos vocês que estão no verão sintam algum conforto no fato de que, esse ano, o Winter Bash também está acontecendo em Português, Espanhol, Japonês e Russo, graças ao trabalho dos nossos Gerentes de Comunidades internacionais.*

2: *A Universidade Winter Bash não é reconhecida por nenhum órgão de educação superior, em lugar nenhum… **Ainda**.*

Comment: +1 Pelo quadrinho :D

Comment: Gabe dá para corrigir o quadradinho, onde está "**as** vezes você tem que **se** arriscar" deveria ser "**às** vezes você tem que arriscar". Eu tomei a liberdade de levar a sua tradução para o PL e fui logo advertido ;)

Comment: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/214/announcing-winter-bash-2015#comment609_214

Comment: @JorgeB. Atualizado! O pessoal lá não perdoa, **mesmo**...

Comment: @Gabe esqueceu de tirar o **se** arriscar...

Comment: @JorgeB. Ah... Não sabia que ficava ruim em pt-pt. Em pt-br é comum. Vou mudar (meu dia inteiro vai ser mexendo em imagens, pelo visto `:D`)

Comment: @Gabe "você tem que **se** arriscar" acho que não está correto. Mas vou perguntar no PL.

Comment: @JorgeB. Sem problema, já foi removido mesmo. Pode atualizar lá.

Comment: Agora que acabou, bem que poderiam postar todos os chapéis, inclusive os secretos ne e como obtê-los.

Answer (score 6):

Isso me lembra muito um jogo que eu costumava jogar algum tempo atrás.

[image: Team Fortress 2]

Comment: Que jogo é esse?

Comment: @JorgeB. [Team Fortress 2](http://www.teamfortress.com)

Comment: @Gabe não conhecia por acaso.

Comment: @JorgeB. Muito bom jogo... Acho que foi o último FPS que eu gostei!

Comment: Essa imagem me lembrou o [@meuchapeu](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/17717/meuchapeu) usando chapéu.